# Excluding MDRT% tables from ALL_TABLES view in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to retrieve all tables in a particular schema using the following query:

```
SELECT OWNER || '.' || TABLE_NAME
  from sys.all_tables
 where secondary = 'N' and owner = 'TEST'
```

This query worked perfectly for me until today when I realized that the same query is behaving differently between 11.2.0.3 and later versions of Oracle. From Oracle 11.2.0.4 onwards, the same query also returns some additional tables, all starting with name MDRT.

I've verified that similar tables exist in both 11.2.0.3 and 11.2.0.4 DBs (noticed it on 12c also). A little googling about what these tables were revealed that they're created by Oracle whenever a spatial index is created. I looked at the schema of `all_tables` to see if I could use any of the columns to try and exclude these additional tables didn't succeed.

The most surprising thing is that I couldn't find any articles on SO or Oracle forums discussing this. This is rather annoying.

Comment: You're asking how to exclude them from the view, not just from your query (with `and table_name not like 'MDRT%'`)?

Comment: Oh no. I don't want want to modify data in any way. I just need to show the connected user all the tables that he owns in my app. I need to hide these additional tables somehow. I did try using not LIKE and it works with my test data but the names in some other DBs start with MDXT instead of MDRT. I'm just trying to find a more generic solution here. Of course I'd have to fall back to MD% is nothing else works.

Comment: Not sure why you'd have tables for an index, or an index would appear in this view; but I don't have the right versions or any spatial background to poke around. But, do those also appear in [`all_sdo_index_info`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_objrelschema.htm#sthref305)? If so you could use that to exclude them, maybe.

Comment: Yes, @AlexPoole, the tables are created to store/manage the node-levels of the R-tree index used for spatial indexing. The create index syntax for SDO spatial indexes includes storage params, but not the physical table name (unfortunately.) Also, yes, these are included in all_sdo_index_info (or user_sdo_index_info.)

Answer (score 0):

As @AlexPoole explained, these MDRT tables can be excluded by name. Here is one specific example to help you (and others) with this recurrant issue:

```
    SELECT 
         AT.OWNER || '.' || AT.TABLE_NAME
    from 
          sys.all_tables AT,
          MDSYS.all_sdo_index_info SI   /* here are the sdo_index details */
 where 
        AT.secondary = 'N' 
    and AT.owner = 'TEST'
    and AT.owner = SI.sdo_index_owner(+)      /* optionally match schema  */
    and AT.table_name = SI.sdo_index_table(+) /* optionally match table   */
    and SI.sdo_index_table is null            /* force no results from SI */
;
```